# Video iframe or embedding it?

Tags: iframe, video, html5-video

I am creating a website that will display about 6 videos. We are going to display them full screen. At the moment I have them embedded into the website. I was wondering would be be better practice to use an iframe?

I am interested in what you think.

This is my first post here, so apologies if I am posting in the wrong place.

Thanks.

Comment: Iframe? Better? Nope.

Comment: It was suggested that iframes were not great for having a link to videos, but would embedding the videos on the site not have an even worse user experience?